# How connect GeoServer to existing Mongo database?

Tags: geoserver, mongodb

I'm trying to connect existing database in MongoDB to GeoServer.
I connected Mongo to GeoServer, but I can't see exisiting DB. (which I created early by cmd)
However, if I create new db from GeoServer, I can see it in Mongo and in GeoServer. 
[image: view geoserver]
[image: view mongo db]

How published exsisting db in GeoServer? 
If I need a special schema, how create it?

Answer (score 1):

So, I answer for my question. 
I should create geometry index like here [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-indexes)

```
db.collection.createIndex( { <location field> : "2dsphere" } )
```

Comment: If this was the answer to your question please accept it